# Golang: unmarshal json object into a slice

Tags: json, go

I have JSON like

```
{
  "a": {"key": "a", "value": 1,},
  "b": {"key": "b", "value": 1,},
}
```

Is there a way to unmarshal it into `[]*struct {Key string; Value int}`, preserving the order of the structures?

If I unmarshal the JSON into `map[string]*struct {Key string; Value int}` and then convert the map into a slice, I'll lose the order of the structures.

Comment: No, of course not. Unless you write your own json.Unmarshaler. Duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way that I found was to use [`jsonparser.ObjectEach`](https://github.com/buger/jsonparser#objecteach):

```golang
import "github.com/buger/jsonparser"

...

var ss []*struct{Key string; Value int}
err = jsonparser.ObjectEach(data, func(key []byte, value []byte, dataType jsonparser.ValueType, offset int) error {
    var s struct{Key string; Value int}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(value, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *ss = append(*ss, &s)
    return nil
})
```

Answer (score 1):

To preserve order, use [Decoder.Token](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder.Token) and [Decoder.More](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder.More) to walk through the top-level JSON object.

```
r := strings.NewReader(`
 {
   "a": {"key": "a", "value": 1},
   "b": {"key": "b", "value": 1}
 }`)

d := json.NewDecoder(r)
t, err := d.Token()
if err != nil || t != json.Delim('{') {
    log.Fatal("expected object")
}
var result []*element
for d.More() {
    k, err := d.Token()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var v element
    if err := d.Decode(&v); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    result = append(result, &v)
    fmt.Println("key:", k, "value:", v)
}
```

[Run it on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/uzF59HAzbL-)

Change the calls to log.Fatal to the error handling appropriate for your application.

This answer edits the JSON in the question to make the JSON valid.

The field names in the struct element type must be [exported](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers).

Answer (score -1):

You could use the map[string]interface{} to unmarshal the json string.
The code is this

```
func test() {
    jsonStr := `
 {
   "a": {"key": "a", "value": 1},
   "b": {"key": "b", "value": 1}
 }`
    var mapResult map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &mapResult)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("JsonToMapDemo err: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(mapResult)
}
```

the output is:
map[a:map[key:a value:1] b:map[key:b value:1]]